# SilverStripe Display logic duplicate error

Tags: php, silverstripe

I get an error in SilverStripe for duplication when using "DisplayLogicWrapper::create" it does it no matter if its upload field or gridfield or any other seems the same issue. Any help is appreciated!

PHP 5.6.30,  silverstripe/cms 3.5.3, unclecheese/display-logic 1.5
plugin: https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-display-logic/tree/1.5.0#dealing-with-non-standard-form-fields

```
private static $has_one = array(
  'IntroBackgroundIMG' => 'Image',
);

DisplayLogicWrapper::create(
  UploadField::create('IntroBackgroundIMG', 'Background Image'))
  ->displayIf("BackgroundType")->isEqualTo("img")
  ->end(),
```

error received:

```
[User Error] collateDataFields() I noticed that a field called 
'IntroBackgroundIMG' appears twice in your form: '(unknown form)'. One is a 
'UploadField' and the other is a 'UploadField'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this module, but it looks like you're trying to display the UploadField conditionally, in which case perhaps you need to ensure that the default UploadField that is scaffolded automatically gets removed first:

```
public function getCMSFields()
{
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    $fields->removeByName('IntroBackgroundIMG');
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', DisplayLogicWrapper...
```

Comment: yeah ive done that one myself not sure if thats the right one and if i will not run in any problems later, will see i guess! if you have more ideas let me know cheers!